# C# IMemoryCache - Modify object property without updating memory cache

Tags: c#, memorycache

I am using Memory cache to retreive object. However if I modify property its automatically updated in cache without calling `MemoryCache.Set`. Btw we are talking about Asp.Net Core **IMemoryCache**.

I have issue which is kinda strange. I retreive object from database and set it to cache. It has property **Childrens**. If I navigate in Blazor to children page and then move back somehow parent's property **Childrens** is changed. Only code where I am setting "= ..." property is while creating memory object. Then I just using simple `Childrens.Where`. Solution to this would be getting object from Memory Cache which is not automatically updated when Blazor do some stuff to my object.

Comment: Weird. Definitely netcore issue. Removing AsNoTracking resolved issue

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129389/how-do-you-do-a-deep-copy-of-an-object-in-net

Comment: @HansPassant wow thanks. However I thought for something already implemented. Anyway thanks for solution for deep copy

Comment: I had this issue too it's not related to AsNoTracking, opened an issue: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/21405

Comment: @Zulander sad there is not copy but ref :/

Comment: This totally breaks internal use of `ConcurrentDictionary` for cached entries and the consistency of the items.. imagine that someone accidentally updates the object property and the other person reads the dirty item.. or both work on that same item at that same time!

Comment: @GumowyKaczak my intentions is not to work with cached items like "updates". My intention is just to read faster than loading it from db. While during editing I am loading it freshly from DB